# Jenkins multi-configuration project: skip master checkout

Tags: jenkins

I use Jenkins multi-configuration projects to build on multiple platforms and compilers (Visual studio, gcc etc).  Jenkins performs a checkout on the master node *before* doing an SCM checkout for each matrix job.

Why is this extra checkout necessary?
Can it be turned off to save time/disk?

Comment: I would also like to know why the sub configuration each are checked out separately?